# Simultaneous solutions to polynomials over reals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

If I have k degree-2 homogenous polynomials of n variables over the reals, with n>k, should I always have nonzero common solutions? Generically I think the common solution set should be an n-k manifold, but can something go wrong non-generically? Thanks.

Comment: This is already false in very small examples because of positivity, e.g. consider $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 0$.

Comment: That isn't homogeneous, but x^2+y^2=0 is already a counterexample for homogeneous. Okay, so is this true over the complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, over the complex numbers it follows from a generalization of Bezout's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The proof that $k < n$ homogeneous polynomials $f_1, \ldots, f_k \in \mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ have a common nonzero root in $\mathbb C^n$ is actually kind of fun. You prove that every irreducible component of $V(f_1,\ldots,f_k)$ has dimension $\geq n-k$ by a repeated application of Krull's Hauptidealsatz (Principal Ideal Theorem). Since $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ have a common zero at the origin, their intersection is therefore nonempty, thus has dimension $\geq n-k > 0$. Thus, removing the origin doesn't make it empty.

This is actually a way you can *prove* that subvarieties of a projective variety always intersect as long as the sums of the codimensions is at most the dimension.